# Ubuntu Software is closing when I select application to install

Tags: 20.04, software-center

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4 Focal Fossa. When I launch the Software Center, it is opening so that I can select an application to install. When I click on an application icon the description window is being opened and has been automatically closed. Why? I cannot install an application from the Ubuntu Software. The command line APT tool is normally working. How can I fix the problem with the Ubuntu Software application?

Comment: Snapcraft, which the Software Center uses in the background, is experiencing intermittent outages today due to a firewall issue on their part. It should be back up-and-running soon (hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem. Try if it worked for you

```
sudo apt-get purge libssl-dev
```

Comment: I did nothing. Simply, It works again normally.

Comment: how did you fix it i just did sudo apt-get purge libssl-dev and it works normally

Comment: I think it was not a problem on my computer. Maybe, it was bad connection with the repository server. I don't know.

Comment: oh the same thing must have happened to me too